# Behavior of Match-Anything Pattern Rules in makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Let's say my source is `test.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("%s\n", "hi");
}
```

I want the executable called `test` to be created in a folder called `bin`. So my `makefile` is:

```
all:bin/test
```

When I execute `make`, I expect the following built-in rule to happen:

```
%: %.c
#  recipe to execute (built-in):
    $(LINK.c) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

because the target `%` should match `bin/test` and since `test.c` exists, it should execute the recipe. However, `make` says: `No rule to make target 'bin/test', needed by 'all'.  Stop.`

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `%` matches `bin/test`, then the prerequisite is `bin/test.c`, which does not exist. So Make rejects that implicit rule in its search for a rule to build `bin/test`. It finds no other rule which fits the bill, and tells you so.

If you try to build `test`, or move `test.c` into `bin/`, then Make will use this rule.

If you want to build binaries in `bin/` from sources in the working directory, you can write your own pattern rule, something that looks like:

```
bin/%: %.c
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand now. One side question: Why would make reject the implicit rule instead of trying to create `bin/test.c`? I say this because the rule is not a "terminal rule". From the manual: One choice is to mark the match-anything rule as terminal by defining it with a double colon. When a rule is terminal, it does not apply unless its prerequisites actually exist.

Comment: @secluded: What makes you think it doesn't? What rule do you expect it to use, to build `bin/test.c`?

Comment: I see. So it does try to make it, but at the end, no rule is found. For example `%.c: %.y` applies but there is no rule for `%.y`. Is that correct?

Comment: @secluded: Broadly, yes.

Comment: If you want to see all the contortions make goes through on your behalf, try running with `-d` :)